# PHP If-Statements Not Working for Form

Tags: php, forms, if-statement

I am getting unexpected T_ELSES.  Please help

```
<?php
$password = $_POST['password'];
$submit = $_POST['submit'];
if ($password == "lol") {
 if ($password) {
  if ($submit) {
   echo "Logged in";
   }
  } else {
  echo "Wrong Pass";
  }
  } else {
  echo "Please fill in all fields.";
  }
 } else {
 echo "Please click submit";
}
?>
```

Either it is just saying please click submit or it gives me unexpected errors or it doesn't detect please fill in all fields.  Please help me and fix up my code thanks

Question:  Whats the problem

Comment: You have an extra else there at the bottom

Comment: @Asad fixed that and I still get unexpected on 15.  Please help :( CRIES

Comment: The logic in this script is weird

Comment: And the error results from not bothering to properly indent code.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you require something like this:

```
<?php
$password = $_POST['password'];
$submit   = $_POST['submit'];
if ($password) {
    if ($password == "lol") {
        if ($submit) {
            echo "Logged in";
        } else {
            echo "Please click submit";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Wrong Pass.";
    }
} else {
    echo "Please fill in all fields.";
}
```

Note that I am only attempting to fix syntactical issues, I cannot guess the logic of your script.

I have updated to reflect your comment.

Comment: when I dont fill in password it says wrong pass, when I do not click submit and access the form action directly, wrong pass.  I don't want wrong pass for everything, I want it to show the other errors like if I dont fill in password field it will say please fill in all fields, and if I directly access next.php [form action] it says please click submit.

Comment: looked at the update.  Works well but when I directly access the form it says Please fill in all fields.  Why?  Please fix.  Thank you for this code it works well.

Comment: It will output "Please fill in all fields" if no value (or a falsy value) is provided for the password field (for whatever reason)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $submit = $_POST['submit'];

    if ($password == "lol") 
    {
        if ($password) 
        {
            if ($submit) 
            {
                    echo "Logged in";
            }
        } 
        if(!$password)
        {
                echo "Wrong Pass";
        }
    } 
    if(!$password !== "lol")
    {
                echo "Please fill in all fields.";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to your problem please refer the code  snippet mentioned below

```
    if(!empty($submit))
    {
  if(!empty($password))
  {
     if($password=='lol')
     {
        echo "Logged in";
      }
     else
     {
         echo "Wrong Pass";
     }
  }
  else
  {
     echo "Please fill in all fields.";
   }
}
else
{
echo "Please click submit";
 }
```